# How to make PhpStorm/WebStorm scope highlighting look more expressive?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, syntax-highlighting

When I first learned Java, I was using an IDE called "BlueJ." It had this feature called "Scope Highlighting" which made it very easy to read blocks of code. See picture below:

[image: Scope Highlighting BlueJ]

As you can see on the first picture, on BlueJ the whole Background of a scope is highlighted with one color.

In PhpStorm or even in most of IDE's today, I get only a highlighting for a scope, which I set the cursor on, and only in a very minimalist way, as you can see on the left side of the picture below:

[image: Scope Highlighting PHPStorm]

Is there a way, or a Plugin for PhpStorm out there, to get it to look more like BlueJ's scope Highlighting???

Thanks

edit:

What I've have found out so far:
There is something alike for HTML, (Setting>Editor>General>Appearance:Enable HTML/XML tag tree highlighting:Set opacity higher than 0) Then you will get this:

[image: HTML Tag tree Highlighting]

Something like this for the other languages (PHP, JS,...) would make me really happy :)

Comment: please see [WEB-2390](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2390) - is it a feature you are looking for?

Comment: Well a kind of.. What i see there, is that they highlight the text of every function that is inside of another function with different colors, but in my eyes that doesn't make it better. They divide into two styles: 1 Different colors for different functions inside other functions. 2 The old known syntax highlighting without any Scope highlighting . What i want is "the old known syntax highlighting" within the background highlighting of the scopes. Like on the BlueJ picture.

Comment: An honorable alternative migth be the plugin: rainbow brackets
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10080-rainbow-brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I have found two solutions for this.

1. The plugin `Rainbow Brackets`, makes it easier to visually find the corresponding bracket.
   [image]

Also, it provides the option to highlight the current scope by `Ctrl + Right Mouse Click` or `Ctrl + Shift + Plus`. The name of the Shortcut is: `Plugins | Rainbow Brackets | Highlight Current Scope` and the highlighting looks like this:

[image]

2. The built-in shortcuts to jump to the matching bracket or the one at the code block start/end. Though it does not highlight anything, you can quickly find the matching bracket. Check your ide-settings for the shortcut: `Editor Actions | Move Caret to Matching Brace` / `Editor Actions | Move Caret to Code Block End` / `Editor Actions | Move Caret to Code Block Start`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will also like the VSCode extension "Blockman". It highlights nested code blocks based on curly/square/round brackets, html/xml tags and Python/Yaml indentation. (I am the author of Blockman).
.

[image: vscode extension blockman]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but this plugin is not available for WebStorm/PhpStorm